# Why findById returns (User & { _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId; }) | null they User | null

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

This is my first time using typescript and mongoose. Here's my code what I did.

**type**

```
export interface User extends Document {
  _id: ObjectId;
  lastName: string;
}
```

**Schema**

```
const userSchema = new Schema<User>({
  lastName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
});
```

**model**

```
const User = model<User>('user', UserSchema, 'users');
```

**request**

```
const user = await User.findById(userId).exec();
```

I expect the `user` variable to be of type `User | null`.but i get `(User & {_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId;}) | null`. what am I doing wrong how can I fix it ?

Comment: You just do not need _id, right?

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong. It's just that the result from a mongodb query would be your model along with the mongodb identifier in `_id` so you don't need to have included that in your `User` model to begin with since that is not an actual real property of your model but rather a surrogate property that only appears when your user models go in a mongodb database

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta _id is needed

Comment: @apokryfos See when I don't declare _id in User, _id becomes any

Comment: What exactly seem to be the problem with the type `(User & {_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId;}) | null`?

Answer (score 1):

> I expect the `user` variable to be of type `User | null`

Well, this just happens to be an invalid expectation.

In [the source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/index.d.ts), the `Model<User>.findById(…).exec()` call is explicitly typed to return:

```
Promise<HydratedDocument<User, {}, {}> | null>
```

… which eventually resolves to:

```
Promise<(User & { _id: ObjectId }) | null>
```

The `& { _id: ObjectId }` part is always added, regardless of anything, and there doesn't seem to be much you can do about it, other than just accept this typing (which shouldn't be too problematic).

#### References:

- definition of `Model.findById()`: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/index.d.ts#L856
- definition of `Query.exec()`: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/index.d.ts#L2096
- definition of `HydratedDocument<…>`: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/index.d.ts#L737
- definition of `Require_id<…>` (internal): https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/index.d.ts#L735